# Custom login property Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I have this custom function for atempting to login in Laravel 8

```
 protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $this->credentials($request);
        $credentials['estado']=1;
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $credentials, $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }
```

How I can make to accept the login atempt when  `$credentials['estado']` also has 2 as value.
Don't know how to make it accept multiple values.

I managed to make the custom function accept the value of 1 but dunno how to make it accept multiple `$credentials['estado']` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in attemptLogin() method, instead you can customize the crededentials() method in LoginController like this:

```
// login, if user have like a following described data in array
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $username = $this->username();

    return [
        $username => $request->get($username),
        'password' => $request->get('password'),
        'estado' => [ 1, 2 ], // OR condition
    ];
}
```

**Answer for comments:**

Honestly in my experience I didn't have that case, but if you want to redirect to the another view on failed login (for specific field 'estado'), you can customize the "sendFailedLoginResponse" method, and add some additional if-condition for checking the 'estado'.
As the "sendFailedLoginResponse" method will be called only for getting failed login response instance, then you can check: is that fail comes from 'estado' field actually. Something like this:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    // custom case, when login failed and estado is 2
    if ($request->get('estado') == 2) {
        return view('some.specific.view');
    }
    // laravel by default implementation
    else {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Remember, in this case (when we're redirecting the user to some page) we actually not redirecting as for always, but instead we're just returning a view. We do that because I think you don't want to let the users to open that specific view page anytime their want, as you need to let them see that page only for specific case. But when you'll do the actual redirect, then you will let the users to visit that page with some static URL.
Of course, you can do some additional stuff (add something in DB or the Session, and check is the request comes actually from 'estado' fails, but not from any user), but this could be a headeche for you, and in my opinion that will not be a real laravel-specific code.

Anyway, this is the strategy. I don't think, that this is mandatory, but this can be do your work easy and secure.

Note: I've got this deafault implementations from "AuthenticatesUsers" trait (use use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;). In any time you can get some available methods from there and override them in your LoginController, as the LoginController used that as a trait.

Comment: In that case should create that function in the LoginController then I suppose. Let me test and I woul tell you if there is any problems or if it works as I expect.

Comment: Also estado is a value the user table has. I plan to use it as a flag to see if the user is soft deleted, its normal or has de default password, thats why I wanted to add the estado = 2 in the condition of trying to log in. So not sure if estado should also have the $request->get(). I will test and if it works mark it as an answer and if it doesn't work as expected then I will make another comment.

Comment: It worked as intended, by the way @boolfalse do you know exactly what function should I custom to make the login send me to another view if when loggin in estado value of 2.

Comment: I've written some stuff about that in updated version )

Comment: thanks for the reply @boolfalse but I plan to redirect the users when estado =2 to a different view not because of a failed login. estado =2 in this case means the user has the default password, I want to make the user change the password the first time they log because by default the password is the same as the username when it is created and that is when estado=2. Thats why I need to redirect with login to a different view, in this case to the view for reset the password. Sorry if I wasn't to specific before. Not sure if I made myself 100 % clear now, english is not my main language.

Comment: The default password is the same as the username. Thats why it must make the user the first time it logs in not go to the home view but to the resetpassword view, after the password is reset I make estado = 1 and then everytime I log in the user goes to home view as expected.